# How to skip processing a cell in Excel if the condition is false for that cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table in Excel that I would like to find matching rows and columns in it.

Here is a MWE:

[image: MWE_input]

The output that I am trying to get is as follows:

[image: MWE_output_expected]

When I use a formula which only includes the IF function (e.g., `=IF(B2="x";$B$1)` for the first column and `=IF(B2="x";A2)` for the second column), the result is quite complicated:

[image: MWE_output_actual]

Is there a way to skip processing a cell if the condition is not satisfied?

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? You may have access to the `FILTER()` function which would be one way to do this. I'm sure there are others and knowing the version will help.

Comment: I have been using Excel Microsoft 365 (Version 16.69.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what your formula is to get that result, you can filter that result for just the values that aren't `FALSE`. I setup a sheet like this with your results hard-coded into `A1:B9`:

[image: Setup]

The formula in `D1` is this:

```
=LET(result,A1:B9,FILTER(result,OFFSET(result,,,,1)<>FALSE))
```

You would need to replace `A1:B9` with whatever your complicated `IF()` formula is. Here's how it works:

- `=LET(result,A1:B9,` defines the results so we can later reference it by name instead of having to re-perform the calculation again later. It also makes it easier to debug.
- `OFFSET(result,,,,1)` extracts just the first column of that result. All those commas are because we're skipping the parameters for offset rows, offset columns, and height. By default, it'll be 0 rows, 0 columns, and the same height as the original.
- `FILTER(result,OFFSET(result,,,,1)<>FALSE)` will return only the rows from `result` where the value in the first column is not `FALSE`.

Comment: I just used a regular IF formula and copied it by dragging the fill handle for each cell accordingly.